# sugarcrm, cannot send campaign emails

Tags: email, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM 6.5 (from upgrade) and cannot send any campaign emails. Test emails ("Send Test") send out fine immediately, but when I choose "Send Emails" nothing gets sent, nor queued in the sugar queue. I'm trying to debug for 3 days, any input would be appreciated.
Job schedulers are configured to run evey 10 minutes, so is cron.

Comment: if u finally make it work, notice me please. :)

Answer (score 0):

check EmailManDelivery.php file.
change `$outboundEmailAccount->mail_sendtype) === 'smtp'` to `strtolower($outboundEmailAccount->mail_sendtype) === 'smtp')` .
it should fix the issue